# How to upload a file in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver

I have a web mapping application that consists of: GeoServer + PostGIS + OpenLayers.

I need to implement an Export/Import mechanisms of my vector data.

For export, I've developed a custom WPS that gets the vector data as GML using WFS GetFeature request, then save it to a file, then return its URL to the front-end to be downloaded.

For import, I want to do the reverse: upload the GML file from the front-end to the GeoServer, then create WFS-T Insert requests to insert the data to my layer.

My problem is now how to upload the GML file to GeoServer, and how to synchronize the upload process with the process of WFS-T Insert.

There was a community plugin "Resumable REST Upload" that uploads files, but it does not exist I then new versions of GeoServer. And If I use it, how to do I synchronize it with the WFS_T Insert process?

Comment: why not use a simple WFS getFeatures to fetch the file and WFS-T to upload it?

Comment: @IanTurton thanks for your reply. How to upload the file using WFS-T?

Comment: you read each feature and put it into an insert transaction

Comment: Why not use Geonode or geoshape?

Comment: Did you have a look at GeoServer docs? https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/importer/using.html

Comment: I think @IanTurton 's solution is the best. Thanks a lot.